# Create custom log file for application installation

Tags: install4j

I am creating Installer for one of my product. During the course of installation I want to log Specific instillation information in a log file.

By default install4j is logging all info in installation.txt file.
I want to create custom log file to log specific log info not all info.

How can I create my own log file? How can I put specific information to this log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for creating custom log files, you would have to do that with your own Java code.

However, there are several "log..." methods in the Util class that allow you to write your own logging messages to the standard log file:

http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/Util.html